# How to customize the appearance of the chat window of google-dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

"Hello everyone,

I'm currently working on integrating Google Dialogflow into my project, and I would like to customize the appearance of the chat window to match the branding and design of my application. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this? I would appreciate any insights, tips, or resources on modifying the chat window's colors, fonts, layout, or any other visual aspects.

Thank you in advance for your help!"

Answer (score 0):

Try ChatGPT, prompt maybe like "Show code to customize Dialogflow as per my website branding".